# jqPlot change axis tick labels colors individually

Tags: jqplot

In jqPlot, is it possible change the color of the axis tick labels individually?

For example, I want them all black, except I want two of them to be blue. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that even examples and options we can provide a single font family, color to all of the ticks, you only can define different colors for different series in your jqplot charts